# getting error while trying to use ground method in nltk_contrib.timex

Tags: python, nltk

```
import datetime
from nltk_contrib import timex

now = datetime.date.today()
basedate = timex.Date(now.year, now.month, now.day)

print timex.ground(timex.tag("Hai i would like to go to mumbai 22nd of next month"), basedate)

print str(datetime.date.day)
```

when i am trying to run the above code i am getting the following error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk_contrib/timex.py", line 250, in ground
    elif re.match(r'last ' + month, timex, re.IGNORECASE):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'month' referenced before assignment
```

what should i do to rectify this error?

Comment: Sounds like you should consider filing a bug on github: https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timex` module has a bug where a global variable is referenced without assignment in the `ground` function.

To fix the bug, add the following code which should start at line 171:

def ground(tagged_text, base_date):

```
# Find all identified timex and put them into a list
timex_regex = re.compile(r'<TIMEX2>.*?</TIMEX2>', re.DOTALL)
timex_found = timex_regex.findall(tagged_text)
timex_found = map(lambda timex:re.sub(r'</?TIMEX2.*?>', '', timex), \
            timex_found)

# Calculate the new date accordingly
for timex in timex_found:
    global month # <--- here is the global reference assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above about adding month as a global variable causes other problems when timex is called multiple times in a row, because variables are not reset unless you import again. This happens for me in a deployed environment in AWS Lambda.

A solution that isn't super pretty but will not cause problems is just to set the month value again in the ground function:

```
def ground(tagged_text, base_date):

    # Find all identified timex and put them into a list
    timex_regex = re.compile(r'<TIMEX2>.*?</TIMEX2>', re.DOTALL)
    timex_found = timex_regex.findall(tagged_text)
    timex_found = map(lambda timex:re.sub(r'</?TIMEX2.*?>', '', timex), \
            timex_found)

    # Calculate the new date accordingly
    for timex in timex_found:
        month = "(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september| \
        october|november|december)" # <--- reset month to the value it is set to upon import
```